# using crypto libraries with dart2js

Tags: javascript, dart, google-cloud-functions, cryptography, dart2js

I'm facing a challenge when using `https://pub.dev/packages/dart_jsonwebtoken` with Firebase Functions.

I used this [article](https://medium.com/icnh/writing-cloud-functions-in-dart-b7e62192b3bc) to enable Firebase Functions with Dart code, but when it comes to using crypto libraries, I'm getting following error:

> Error: Value of "this" must be of type nullish or must be the global object

Here's sample code I'm using:

```
Future<void> simpleSign() async {
  String token;

  final jwt = JWT(
    {
      'id': 123,
      'server': {
        'id': '3e4fc296',
        'loc': 'euw-2',
      }
    },
    issuer: 'https://github.com/jonasroussel/dart_jsonwebtoken',
  );

  // Sign it
  final pem = rsaPrivKey;
  final key = RSAPrivateKey(pem);

  token = await jwt.sign(key, algorithm: JWTAlgorithm.RS256);

  print('Signed token: $token\n');
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas how to move forward. I want to use this feature to create JWS for further usage.

Comment: Your question is about libraries, but I don't see any import statements or indication of the libraries. Why not include them (+ version number)? Have you looked into bug DB's?

Comment: I'm using the following libs:

import 'package:dart_jsonwebtoken/dart_jsonwebtoken.dart';
import 'package:firebase_functions_interop/firebase_functions_interop.dart';

I'm on Dart v2.9.3, because dart2js compiler doesn't work on higher versions.